# how to snmp an array of ip addresses for php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, snmp

I have an array of ip addresses and i want to snmpwalk those ip addresses but i can only do so by specifying the position of each ip address e.g

this is what my array of ip addresses look like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10.100.66.25
    [1] => 10.96.100.1
)
```

In the future i will add more Ip addresses.

This is the snmp code that i want to execute:

```
$dbconnect=new mysqli('localhost','root','','helena');
$secondQuery = snmpwalk( $switchArray[1], "iut-mon", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1");
```

How would I snmpwalk all the ip addresses in the array instead of specifying one?

Comment: With a loop? A simple foreach loop should do the trick.

Comment: Thank You . This helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop your array and merge the result, like simplified below:

```
$dbconnect = new mysqli('localhost','root','','helena');
$ips = ['10.100.66.25', '10.96.100.1'];
$results = [];

foreach ($ips as $key => $value) {
    array_merge($results, snmpwalk($value, "iut-mon", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1")); // add the array to the $results
}

print_r($results); // print the list of results array
```